# Sending data from Android to C++ server via Bluetooth

Tags: android, c++, c, sockets, bluetooth

So I'm currently trying to send basic characters from my android device to a C++/C server. I know there is a lot of documented methods of sending and recieving to Java servers but I have been stumped on how to do this via bluetooth to a totally different language.

The common method of using bluetooth sockets via

```
 createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID)
```

does not seem to be the correct approach because it is meant for use with a parallel server using the listen function.

On the C++ side this is the best implementation I could find:

http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html

But I have been having trouble finding a way to get my java android code to talk to this c server code.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to do this?

Comment: try to reuse the code of bluetoothchat come along with android sdk.  i did the same and successfully done a lot of communication with the server running in C.

Comment: what was your C code like? My phone application as of this moment says it is connected to the device, and calling socket.isConnected returns true. 

But for some reason in the C server it still hangs in the accept() loop and does not show that anything is being accepted even though in my phone it says a connection is clearly established.

Comment: i used the the rfcomm-server.c code from [link](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html). it will be better to know what is the return value in listen() function. try to check the return value==0 before calling accept.